# Powercenter Express wait task

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Does PowerCenter Express have a workflow wait task? I know PowerCenter does but I'm trying to create a workflow that waits on the arrival of a flatfile but can't figure out how to create the wait task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workflows in PowerCenter express edition currently lack the support for EventWait task. But you can work around it by using the command task by writing a script that waits for the file arrival and using that with CommandTask.